# How to dynamically map a list of children objects of same parent class in Java

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Using SpringBoot, as REST response, my controller has to return a list of `MenuDTO` which is a parent class of `SimpleMenuDTO` and `TastingMenuDTO`.

I am using ModelMapper to map entity to DTO.

```
public abstract class MenuEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private RestaurantEntity restaurant;
}
```

```
public class SimpleMenuEntity extends MenuEntity {
    private final Set<MenuSectionEntity> sections = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class TastingMenuEntity extends MenuEntity {
    private BigDecimal price;
    private final Set<ProductEntity> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class MenuDTO {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private char menuType;
    private Long restaurantId;
}
```

How can I handle this situation?
I am able to change the entities and DTOs.

**UPDATE**
The main problem here is how to dynamically map a list of `SimpleMenuEntity` and `TastingMenuEntity` in runtime.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: A valid (but horrible) solution is raw types, or using a list of objects.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Because my frontend needs to show the complete list of Menus, and it might be of different types.

Comment: Are you asking how to use ModelMapper to create the entity -> DTO conversion? Or how to output DTO -> rest?

Comment: Well, as the comments and responses were comming, I realise that the problem is with dinamic mapping between base class and children classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
I have to configure the mapper like this:

```
        mapper.createTypeMap(TastingMenuEntity.class, MenuDTO.class)
        .setConverter(mappingContext -> mapper.map(mappingContext.getSource(), TastingMenuDTO.class));
```

```
        mapper.createTypeMap(SimpleMenuEntity.class, MenuDTO.class)
        .setConverter(mappingContext -> mapper.map(mappingContext.getSource(), SimpleMenuDTO.class));
```

So, the final mapping method would be as follows:

```
    public MenuDTO map(MenuEntity entity) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.createTypeMap(TastingMenuEntity.class, MenuDTO.class)
        .setConverter(mappingContext -> mapper.map(mappingContext.getSource(), TastingMenuDTO.class));

        mapper.createTypeMap(SimpleMenuEntity.class, MenuDTO.class)
        .setConverter(mappingContext -> mapper.map(mappingContext.getSource(), SimpleMenuDTO.class));

        return mapper.map(entity, MenuDTO.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Jackson as a project dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

then use [`@JsonTypeInfo` to output a `@type` field](http://federico.defaveri.org/2016/11/20/handling-polymorphism-with-jackson/) that can be used by recipients to distinguish different menus.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=SimpleMenuDTO.class, name="Simple"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TastingMenuDTO.class, name="Tasting")
})
public class MenuDTO {
}
```

which might give JSON like:

```
{
  // Type-specific elements
  "@type" : "Tasting",
  "price" : "10.0",

  // Common elements
  "description" : "",
  "restaurantId" : 1,
  "name" : ""
}
```

If you don't like `@type` then choose your own name with `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, property="menuType")`